# Connect BlackBerry app to PHP web service

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me

How can I make my BlackBerry application send data to a remote server via a PHP web service? I do have some experience with Android and we use kSOAP2 and JSON protocols to pass data to a web service. But on the BlackBerry, I am not sure on how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code is

```
HttpConnection oCon = (HttpConnection)Connection.open(YOUR_SERVER_URL);

URLEncodedPostData oPostData = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);

oPostData.append("param1", "VALUE 1");
oPostData.append("param2", "VALUE 2");

OutputStream streamOut = oCon.openOutputStream();
streamOut.write(oPostData.getBytes());

streamOut.flush();
streamOut.close();
```

For more details please refer to peter_strange's support forum post "[Sample HTTP Connection code and BIS-B Access](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-HTTP-Connection-code-and-BIS-B-Access/td-p/653175)"

This is good to start with.

Comment: Thanks John. that was a great start as you referred.